# What can we say about the closed-form solutions of $ x^q - 2x + 1$ for $\def\N{\mathbb{N}} q \in \N^+$?

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving, closed-form

$\def\N{\mathbb{N}}$

What can we say about the closed-form solutions for $x^q - 2x + 1$ for $q \in \N^+$ ?
I can solve it for small values of $q$ up to 5.
And I wonder what happens next, for $q > 5$ ?

Maybe there are some special functions associated to the solutions of this equation...

Comment: If by "closed-form" solutions, you mean solutions involving radicals, it seems like there won't be any.  That polynomial has the obvious root 1 hence is not irreducible, but it looks like $x^q-2x+1/x-1$ is irreducible (maybe Eisenstein's criterion could be used to prove).  Then if you know Galois Theory and are able to show the Galois Group is $S_{q-1}$, by Galois' Theorem the roots cannot be expressed in terms of radicals.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sharding4 ! Indeed, dividing $x^q - 2x + 1$ by $(x-1)$ we easily obtain $x^{q-1} + x^{q-2} + \cdots + x^2 + x - 1$.  Now I will think how to prove that the Galois Group of this polynomial is $S_{q-1}$. If you have any suggestions or a simple argument don't hesitate to write a comment.

Comment: The polynomial is indeed irreducible, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4120262/104527 for proof link.